# What is the range of $λ$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Suppose $a, b, c$ are the sides of a triangle and no two of them are equal.
Let $λ ∈ IR$. If the roots of the equation $x^
2 + 2(a + b + c)x + 3λ(ab +
bc + ca) = 0$ are real, then what is the range of $λ$?

I got that $$λ ≤\frac{
(a + b + c)^
2}
{3(ab + bc + ca)}$$

After that what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ by triangle inequality, we have

$$|a-b|<c$$

Squaring both sides we get,

$$(a-b)^2<c^2\tag{1}$$

Similarly,

$$(b-c)^2<a^2\tag{2}$$

And

$$(c-a)^2<b^2\tag{3}$$

Adding $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$, we get

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 <2(ab+bc+ca) \Longleftrightarrow (a+b+c)^2 <4(ab+bc+ca)\tag{4}$$

From $(4)$, we get $\lambda <\dfrac{4}{3}$

---

To see why the upper bound is the supremum consider a degenerate triangle with sides $(a,a,c)$,(where $c \rightarrow 0$) and permutations.

For example, when $(a,b,c)=(1,1, 0.01)$, then $\lambda \leq \dfrac{4.0401}{3.0600} \approx 1.321 $

Comment: Should'nt $\lambda$ be less than the minimum possible value of the RHS i.e 1 rather than the largest possible value of RHS of the inequality i.e 4/3 i wrote in the question?Can you tell me if i'm going wrong?

Comment: @ZOZ You are wrong. Take $(a,b,c)=(1,2,2)$ and you will see that $\lambda \leq \frac{25}{24}$, which is greater than $1$.

Comment: @ZOZ: you're right, this answer derives a bound in the wrong direction; we care about the infimum of the expression on the RHS as $a,b,c$ range over all possible sides of a triangle. Moreover, the upper bound in this answer is not tight, since we can't have all three equalities of the form $(a-b)^2=c^2$ hold simultaneously in the limit when the triangle becomes a line segment.

Comment: @amakelov We can't get a tight upper bound in this case as $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.

Comment: @Roby5: Oh, I'm sorry, I meant to say that the RHS can't get arbitrarily close to $4/3$, but I take that back now, I think the supremum is indeed $4/3$, which also follows from my answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Roby5: I might have misunderstood the question, but I believe your answer is wrong or incomplete. I interpreted the question as asking about all possible values of $\lambda$ such that for *any* triangle the quadratic has real roots.

You interpreted it as asking about the range of $\lambda$ for which there exists *some* triangle for which the quadratic has real roots. Your answer gives an upper bound for the RHS and doesn't show that the RHS can get arbitrarily close to it. These are my reasons for the downvote, but the OP should weight in about the question's interpretation.

Comment: @amakelov Is this answer still incomplete? If not kindly remove your downvote.

Comment: @amakelov Right, I too have a doubt about that.Why is Roby5 taking the upper bound of the RHS of inequality.Usually when $x<y$ and $a \geq  y \geq b$ we take that x must be smaller than even the smallest value possible value of y i.e. b.So x<b.

Comment: @ZOZ amakelov's and your problem are different. Both have been addressed in the answer. By the way, your previous statement is wrong. A simple counter-example is $3 <y$, $4 \geq y \geq 2$ . This doesn't imply $3<2$, because $3<2$ is false.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Roby5.

Comment: @ZOZ Still any doubts?

Comment: No no i get it now.It was a silly mistake on my part :-)!

Comment: @ZOZ Delete the thank you comments and other comments not relevant to the question, to prevent overcrowding in the comments section and I will follow suit.

Answer (score 4):

There is a systematic way to get rid of the triangle condition by substituting 
$$a = x + y, b = y + z, c = z + x$$
which comes from the tangents to the incircle, explained e.g. [here](https://mblog1024.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/ravi-substitution-explained/). Now the only condition on $x,y,z$ is that they are positive reals, and additionally they are distinct (because we want $a,b,c$ to be distinct).

The quadratic has real roots iff the discriminant is $\geq 0$, and as you say, if (writing in terms of the new variables)
$$\lambda \leq \frac{4(x+y+z)^2}{3(x^2+y^2+z^2) + 9(xy+yz+zx)}$$
Now we need to find the range of that expression for distinct real $x,y,z$.

Now let $a=x^2+y^2+z^2$, $b=xy+yz+zx$, and observe that $a> b$ from $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2>0$, and moreover $a/b$ can take any value $\alpha> 1$. Hence, since our expression is
$$\frac{4}{3}\frac{a+2b}{a+3b} = \frac{4}{3}\frac{a/b+2}{a/b+3}$$
and we know the range of $a/b$, we get the range of $\lambda$ as well.

Comment: @DeepSea: I believe what I demonstrated broke the back of the problem, and it's a matter of some simple calculation to finish it :) but if you need more details feel free to ask more specific questions :)

Comment: This answer draws upon some good ideas but certainly is an overkill for the above question.

Comment: $a/b$ can get arbitrarily big, by e.g. picking $y=1,z=2$, so that the expression becomes $(x^2+5)/(3x+2)$, and then making $x$ big. The upper bound is established when we let $a/b\to\infty$, which gives precisely $4/3$.